# Trying to split a string in C by a space and use the second word

Tags: c, string

I'm making a client-server program using sockets, and I need to client to be able to send a message to the server as a command, for example 'user 3' which connects the user to user 3. 
So far everything is working but I don't know how to separate the string into its useful parts. I need to first check the command which is 'user' and then check the second word which in this case is '3'.

So far I have only managed to split it using the '\0' delimiter which isn't proving to be all that useful, it only allows me to check is the user has said 'user' or '3'.

```
char receive[1024];
int read = recv(client_socket, &receive, 1024, 0);
receive[read] = '\0';

if (strcmp(receive, "user") == 0) {
    printf("User has requested chat with....");
}
```

Comment: Check `strtok` function. It will walk you over all the tokens - depending on delimiter. `man strtok`.

Comment: Have you tried with something like `strtok()`? Can you show your code snippet where you are splitting  the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case you should be using

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

it finds the substring in the provided string.

For example:

```
char receive[1024];
int read = recv(client_socket, &receive, 1024, 0);
receive[read] = '\0';

if (strstr(receive, "user")) {
    printf("User has requested chat with....");
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but if I had for example 50 users, and the user typed 'user 10' how would I iterate over 50 users to check if 10 was found using strstr

Comment: @SkinnyBetas Sorry I did not understand your question? where and how are you storing `50 users`?

Comment: Sorry was unclear, just an example. I meant if say the user typed 'user 10' that would work if I had an if statement saying if (strstr(receive, "10"). But that would require me to write a statement for every user number wouldnt it

Comment: Consider you are not using `strstr` how are you going to make it work with `strtok` without putting multiple `if`  statments?

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtok` function which two parameters one the string and one the delimiter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char strtest[] ="- This, a string for testing.";
  char * pchs;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" in token:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (strtest," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [strtok()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is what exactly you need. It separates the string with the given delimiters, here it is whitespace.

```c
char receive[1024];
int read = recv(client_socket, &receive, 1024, 0);
receive[read] = '\0';
char *token = strtok(receive, " ");  // get the first part

while (token != NULL) {  // while there still have unprocessed parts
    // handle the commands, values, whatever you want
    if (strcmp(receive, "user") == 0) {
        printf("User has requested chat with....");
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, " ");  // get the next part
}
```